# Modifiying just the <after-sep> in titlesec pacakge

Tags: titlesec

Good day.

I'd like to add some space after each section. I'm using article class and I've looked in the titlesec package to customize this parameter. I've studied couple of questions and mostly people suggest using this command:

```
\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
```

In this case I need to modify each parameter which I don't want to do. **How do I increase the *after-sep* proportionally without dealing with other parameters?**

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section{Header}
\lipsum[1]


\subsection{Subheader}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I want to increase the space between title and the paragraph shown in this picture:

[image: latex.jpg]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out how to help you when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly modify the setting using `\@startsection`; the relevant lines in `article.cls` are

```
% article.cls, line 312:
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

The arguments to `\@startsection` are

1. *name*
2. *level*
3. *indent*
4. *beforeskip* (if negative, suppress indentation on the next paragraph)
5. *afterskip* (if negative, the title is run in)
6. *setup* (commands for typesetting the title)

So you need to modify the *afterskip*, say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {6ex \@plus 1ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: So to answer my bottom line question: there isn't a way to proportionally increase only the after-sep. You need to have the original values and hard code them again.

Comment: @t-my If the `\section` command is defined as in the standard classes, one can extract the value of *beforeskip* and accordingly set the *afterskip*. But it's really easier looking at the definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute the default values for `indent` and `beforeskip` (from `article.cls` as presented by egreg). To suppress indentation on the next paragraph, use starred version of `\titlespacing`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus -.2ex}{6ex plus 1ex}
\begin{document}
  Some text
  \section{First section}
  some text
  \section{Second section}
  some text
\end{document}
```

[image]